# Replacing karma with jasmine-node for my AngularJS tests?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-node

#### Jasmine AngularJS test (passes in `karma start configs/karma.conf.js`)

```
describe('IndexController', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('IndexController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should add name parameter to scope', function () {
        expect(scope.name).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

#### Contents of controllers.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('IndexController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'bob';
});
```

#### Output of: `jasmine-node test/ --junitreport`

```
   Message:
     TypeError: object is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: object is not a function
    at null.<anonymous> (/tmp/tests/test/unit/controllerSpec.js:38:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/tests/test/unit/controllerSpec.js:36:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Comment: Which config file does it use? How does it get hold of the files it's dependent on? I've never used jasmine-node but I'm tryna see if we could debug this together

Comment: Do you import angular-mocks.js on  it? It is needed for module() and inject()

Answer (score 0):

`beforeEach()` taks in a function. Be sure `module('myApp')` and `inject(...)` are returning actual function definitions. Jasmine's beforeEach is like "call the passed function before each test", so you may want:

```
beforeEach( function(){ module('myApp') } );
```

I am unfamiliar with karma, but do use jasmine's `done()` method in my `beforeEach()` like this:

```
var valueForEachTest = null;
beforeEach( function(done) {
  doSomething( function(value){
    valueForEachTest = value;
    done();
  });
} );
```

Not using that `done()` call breaks my tests because I'm doing a few asynchronous call in there (perhaps Jasmine is not waiting for beforeEach to finish?).

Answer (score 0):

Angular is made to run in the browser. It will not run in node. At least, not without [a lot of effort](https://github.com/runvnc/angular-on-server/wiki/Running-AngularJS-on-the-server-with-Node.js-and-jsdom).

There has been an attempt to [port it to node](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angularjs-server), but that project is really intended to render angular pages server side for search engine optimization. Unless you have a really good reason, you shouldn't be trying to test Angular apps in Node.